# Unable to locate package g++-arm-linux-androideabi

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, github-actions, cross-compiling

I have a JNI module and I'm trying to cross compile with GitHub action and the `org.codehaus.mojo:native-maven-plugin` maven plugin, so I wrote the following workflow that worked before I added the installation of the package `arm-linux-androideabi-g++` that the docker image can't find:

```yaml
  elaborate-native-module:
    name: Elaborate native module (${{ matrix.os }} ${{ matrix.architecture }})
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      max-parallel: 2
      matrix:
        os: [windows-latest, ubuntu-latest, macOS-latest]
        java: [18]
        architecture: [x86, x64]
        exclude:
          - os: macOS-latest
            architecture: x86
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    steps:
      - name: Set up JDK ${{ matrix.java }}
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: ${{ matrix.java }}
          distribution: 'zulu'
          architecture: ${{ matrix.architecture }}
      - if: startsWith(matrix.os, 'ubuntu') && startsWith(matrix.architecture, 'x64')
        name: Set up C/C++ compiler
        run: |
          sudo apt update
          sudo apt-get -y install g++-aarch64-linux-gnu arm-linux-androideabi-g++
      - if: startsWith(matrix.os, 'ubuntu') && startsWith(matrix.architecture, 'x86')
        name: Set up C/C++ compiler
        run: |
          sudo apt update
          sudo apt-get -y install doxygen vera++ zlib1g-dev libsnappy-dev \
            g++-multilib
      - if: startsWith(matrix.os, 'windows-latest') && startsWith(matrix.architecture, 'x86')
        name: Set up C/C++ compiler
        uses: egor-tensin/setup-mingw@v2
        with:
          platform: ${{ matrix.architecture }}
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Build native library
        run: mvn -B clean compile -Dproject_jdk_version=${{ matrix.java }} -DskipTests=true --file ./native/pom.xml
      - if: startsWith(matrix.os, 'ubuntu-latest') && startsWith(matrix.architecture, 'x64')
        name: Build native library for aarch64
        run: |
           mvn -B clean compile -Dproject_jdk_version=${{ matrix.java }} -Paarch64-for-unix-x64 -DskipTests=true --file ./native/pom.xml
           mvn -B clean compile -Dproject_jdk_version=${{ matrix.java }} -Parm-eabi-for-unix-x64 -DskipTests=true --file ./native/pom.xml
      - if: github.event_name == 'push' && (endsWith(github.event.head_commit.message, 'Releasing new version') || contains(github.event.head_commit.message, 'Generating external artifacts'))
        name: Push native library
        run: |
          git config user.name "${{ github.event.head_commit.committer.name }}"
          git config user.email "${{ github.event.head_commit.committer.email }}"
          git pull origin ${{github.ref}}
          git add .
          git commit -am "Generated native library on ${{ matrix.os }} ${{ matrix.architecture }}" --allow-empty
          git push
```

... But the workflow fails with this message:

```
Fetched 8180 kB in 2s (4256 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
15 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package arm-linux-androideabi-g++
```

... The code line that doesn't work is `sudo apt-get -y install g++-aarch64-linux-gnu arm-linux-androideabi-g++`: how can I solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `sudo apt-get -y install g++-aarch64-linux-gnu g++-arm-linux-gnueabi`. The related compilation executable is `arm-linux-gnueabi-g++`